# R: Plotly and subplot(): fastest way to create a subplot based on a factor

Tags: r, plotly

I have a `dataframe` such as:

```
 line station   var
1       a 39446
1       b 82964
1       c 57840
1       d 78946
1       e 69972
1       f 14303
1       g 78179
2       a 37738
2       b 62261
2       c 19378
2       d 76435
2       e 17181
2       f 75148
2       g 10882
```

I would like to use plot_ly to create a subplot from these data. I want a barplot with station as x-values, and var as y-values. I want to have two subplots based on line. I know that I could just do:

```
p1 <- plot_ly(data = df[df$line == "1", ], x = ~station, y = ~var, type = "bar")
p2 <- plot_ly(data = df[df$line == "2", ], x = ~station, y = ~var, type = "bar")
p3 <- subplot(p1, p2, nrows = 2)
```

This is kind of repetitive because the code for `p1`and `p2` is basically the same. What is the fastest way to do this natively? I am aware of `facet_grid`and `ggplotly`but would like to it natively in plotly.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can `split` the df, and build each plot. 
Luckily `subplot` supports list and so you can pipe it all:

```
library(plotly)
library(purrr)

df %>% 
    split(df$line) %>% 
    map(~{
        plot_ly(data = .x, x = ~station, y = ~var, type = "bar")
    }) %>% 
    subplot(margin = .05)
```

[image]

Using only base R:

```
splitted_list <- split(df, df$line)

plot_list <- lapply(splitted_list, plot_ly, x = ~station, y = ~var, type = "bar")

subplot(plot_list, margin = .05)
```

Comment: Hello GGamba, thank you. This looks great. Do I understand the `map` function correctly that it takes the piped input, here the splitted df and executes the formula `~{plot_ly(....)}`to it? I am sorry if this is a stupid question, I have no experience using the purrr package, it appears very useful though. I figured out your answer taking the piping away. Could you maybe explain the use of `~{}`? This is new to me. Thank you so much.

Comment: Also, do you happen to know how to adjust the space between the two plots so the tick marks do not overlap as in your picture? Thanks :)

Comment: That's exactly how `purrr` works. `~..` is used to specify that what follow is the function to be applied. In this case the braces `{}` are redundant, as it's only one line function.

Comment: Added `base R` translation and `margin` to avoid overlap

Comment: Cheers mate, awesome. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I seem to get a strange error when I try this on mtcars.

Comment: > p <- mtcars %>%
+   split(mtcars$cyl) %>%
+   map(~{
+     plot_ly(data = .x, x = ~hp, y = ~mpg, type = "scatter")
+   }) %>% 
+   subplot(margin = .05)
Error in as.list.environment(x, all.names = TRUE) : 
  the ... list does not contain 2 elements
> p

Comment: @Mark , I had the same issue with purrr version ‘0.3.2’, but it works with purrr version ‘0.2.2’