# Plotly R subpanel per group /factor

Tags: r, plot, shiny, plotly

I am trying to find an example how to create a plotly plot where there is a subpanel created for each factor in one column, and the y axis  is a value column, and x for instance the date or rowname

For instance if we would take the `mtcars` data frame, group by `cyl` to create 1 subpanel per cyl value, plot `mpg` as y axis and `rowname` as x axis

**variable nr of factors**
In addition, in my intended case I do not know how many unique  factors there will be because that depends on the model that creates my data in the shiny app before the plot stage.

I saw this example, but that plots a panel per variable column rather than a panel per factor:

```
p <- economics %>%
  tidyr::gather(variable, value, -date) %>%
  transform(id = as.integer(factor(variable))) %>%
  plot_ly(x = ~date, y = ~value, color = ~variable, colors = "Dark2",
          yaxis = ~paste0("y", id)) %>%
  add_lines() %>%
  subplot(nrows = 5, shareX = TRUE)
```

If anyone knows a way to get me started or has an existing example on how to do this I would be very grateful

**EDIT**
I tried to build this code but it seems to plot all values in each panel

```
   mydf <- mtcars[ ,names(mtcars)[which(names(mtcars) %in%  c('cyl', 'mpg', 'hp'))]]
plot_ly(data = mydf, x =~hp, y=~mpg, type = 'scatter')


myplotlysub <- function(dat) {
  plot_ly(data = mydf, x =~hp, y=~mpg, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers')
}

p <- mydf %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  do(plot = myplotlysub(.)) %>%
  subplot(nrows = 1) %>%
  layout(
    showlegend = TRUE)
p
```

[image: panels but not correcte]

Comment: Have you seen this SO post: [R: Plotly and subplot(): fastest way to create a subplot based on a factor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42858202/r-plotly-and-subplot-fastest-way-to-create-a-subplot-based-on-a-factor)

Comment: Oh wow thanks Adam. That might just be it. Surprised that didn't show up in all my google and so searches. (Been looking at this occasionally in the past weeks while finishing other parts of my code). Will test it as soon as I get the chance . thanks

Comment: It seems to throw errors for me when I try that solution:

Comment: > p <- mtcars %>%
+   split(mtcars$cyl) %>%
+   map(~{
+     plot_ly(data = .x, x = ~hp, y = ~mpg, type = "scatter")
+   }) %>% 
+   subplot(margin = .05)
Error in as.list.environment(x, all.names = TRUE) : 
  the ... list does not contain 2 elements
> p

Comment: I have updated my answer to address the subplot approach and the error you ran into

Comment: Nice! I've found another way to do it in the meantime. Will share it here tomorrow once I'm behind PC (fooling around through phone with teamviewer at the moment haha)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Using `ggplotly`

One possible way to do the task is to leverage `ggplot2`'s `facet_grid` & then convert the ggplot object into a plotly one using `plotly::ggplotly`.  The `ggplotly` function isn't always great, but if you're familiar with `ggplot2` then it's a quick way to get a plotly plot.  Note since the object returned from `ggplotly` is a plotly object we can further modify it with plotly functions.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

# move rownames to a column for use in `aes()`
my_mtcars = mtcars
my_mtcars$model = rownames(my_mtcars)

# create ggplot
p = ggplot(my_mtcars, aes(x=model, y=mpg)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity') +
  # facet by cyl (drop unused factors in a facet using free_x)
  facet_grid(. ~ cyl, scales = "free_x") +
  labs(x='') + 
  # rotate and size x tick marks
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, 
                                   hjust = 1,
                                   size=5))
# add plotly-ness
ggplotly(p) %>% 
  layout(title="MPG by CYL")
```

[image]

### Using `subplot`

You can alternatively use `plotly::subplot` as pointed out in this [SO Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42858202/r-plotly-and-subplot-fastest-way-to-create-a-subplot-based-on-a-factor).  However, the answer uses `purrr`'s formula syntax which seems to clash with plotly's use of the `~`, and causes an error.  To run w/o error you can avoid using `~var` plotly syntax or use `lapply` instead of `purrr::map`.

A downside of `subplot` compared to `facet_grid` + `ggplotly` is that you end up with varying scaled y-axes; this is something that you'll have to manually address if you want to avoid confusion.

```
library(plotly)
library(purrr)

# using purrr::map
mtcars %>% 
  split(mtcars$cyl) %>% 
  map(~{
    plot_ly(data = .x, 
            x = rownames(.x), 
            y = .x$mpg, 
            type = "bar")
  }) %>% 
  subplot(margin = .05)

# using lapply
mtcars %>% 
  split(mtcars$cyl) %>% 
  lapply(function(x) {
    plot_ly(data = x, 
            x = rownames(x), 
            y = ~mpg, 
            type = "bar")
  }) %>% 
  subplot(margin = .05)
```

[image]

Comment: I know about the ggplot options from the past but I'm trying to do this purely with plotly