# How do I use purrr::map() to create function with plotly subplot() without getting an error?

Tags: r, purrr, r-plotly

I'm looking to use purrr::map() to create a subplot function in plotly. This previous question [R: Plotly and subplot(): fastest way to create a subplot based on a factor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42858202/r-plotly-and-subplot-fastest-way-to-create-a-subplot-based-on-a-factor) provided map as a solution, but it looks like this doesn't work anymore with more recent versions of `purrr`. When I try and run the code below I get `Error in : Can't convert a plotly/htmlwidget object to function`.

In the example below I want 4 charts on 2 rows, with hover info, a shared legend all as a stacked 100% bar chart. Can `purrr::map()` work with this in `plotly`? Thanks in advance for your help.

```
library(purrr)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

#basic dataframe

df <- 
  tibble::tribble(~cakes,~year,~not_sold,~sold,
                  "Cheese Cake",    2018,   21757,  6,
                  "Cheese Cake",    2019,   18115,  200,
                  "Cheese Cake",    2020,   16776,  2920,
                  "Carrot Cake",    2018,   2529,   2,
                  "Carrot Cake",    2019,   2142,   351,
                  "Carrot Cake",    2020,   1662,   298,
                  "Pound Cake", 2018,   7004,   21,
                  "Pound Cake", 2019,   8739,   316,
                  "Pound Cake", 2020,   6832,   2949,
                  "Chocolate Cake", 2018,   23761,  35,
                  "Chocolate Cake", 2019,   18973,  1379,
                  "Chocolate Cake", 2020,   14054,  6065)

#adding percentage columns

df <- 
  df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(total = sold + not_sold,
                pct_sold = (sold/total)*100,
                pct_not = (not_sold/total)*100)
#subplotting

cakes <- 
  df %>% 
    split(.$cakes) %>% 
    purrr::map(.x = df,
               .f = 
        plotly::plot_ly(
          x = ~year, 
          y = ~pct_sold, 
          name = "Cakes sold",
          type = 'bar',
          text = paste0('Cakes sold: ',
                         format(~sold,
                                big.mark = ",")),
          hoverinfo = 'text',
          marker = list(color = 'rgb(0, 169, 244)',
                        width = 2))) %>%
          plotly::add_trace(
            y = ~pct_not,
            name = "Not sold",
            text = paste0('Cakes not sold: ',
                          format(~not_sold,
                                 big.mark = ",")),
            hoverinfo = 'text',
            marker = list(color = 'rgb(230, 230, 230)'),
                          width = 2)) %>%
          plotly::layout(barmode = 'stack') %>%
  plotly::subplot(nrows = 2,
                  margin = .05)

cakes
```

Comment: I am assuming you are iterating over the different subsets of the data generated by split?
In that case you need to specify that in the function somewhere. thankfully it is an easy fix, add `function(data)` in front of the plotly function then wrap that in `{}`. Then inside the original plot_ly call specify the argument `data = data`. This will create a list of the plots. To share them with one legend is beyond my plotly skills, I've done it before, but I would need to work it out again

Comment: Thank you NotThatKindODr! This works!

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the new `dplyr 1.0.0` features to nest your data and create a a dataframe column containing the plots you need.

```
plot_fn <- function(data) {
  plotly::plot_ly(
    data,
    x = ~year, 
    y = ~pct_sold, 
    name = "Cakes sold",
    type = 'bar',
    text = paste0('Cakes sold: ',
                  format(~sold,
                         big.mark = ",")),
    hoverinfo = 'text',
    marker = list(color = 'rgb(0, 169, 244)',
                  width = 2)) %>%
  plotly::add_trace(
    y = ~pct_not,
    name = "Not sold",
    text = paste0('Cakes not sold: ',
                  format(~not_sold,
                         big.mark = ",")),
    hoverinfo = 'text',
    marker = list(color = 'rgb(230, 230, 230)'),
    width = 2)
}

df_plots <- df %>% 
  dplyr::nest_by(cakes) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(plot = list(plot_fn(data)))

df_plots
```

This creates a dataframe with your plotly objects inside it.

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Rowwise:  cakes
  cakes                        data plot    
  <chr>          <list<tbl_df[,6]>> <list>  
1 Carrot Cake               [3 × 6] <plotly>
2 Cheese Cake               [3 × 6] <plotly>
3 Chocolate Cake            [3 × 6] <plotly>
4 Pound Cake                [3 × 6] <plotly>
```

You can then pipe further to generate subplots etc.